# Later.js recur every hour not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, date, laterjs

I'm using Later.js for recurring events. I'm trying to test the `recur()` function and it doesn't seem to be working properly, and I don't know why. Here's my example:

```
var schedule_hourly = later.schedule(later.parse.recur().every(x).hour()),
    start_hourly = moment(start_day + " " + start_time, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm');
var occurrences_hourly = schedule_hourly.next(y, start_hourly);

for (var i = 0; i < occurrences_hourly.length; i++) {
    var execution_dates_hourly = [];
    execution_dates_hourly = moment(occurrences_hourly[i]).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm');
    console.log(execution_dates_hourly);
}
```

Where:

- `x` and `y` are values that I can change;
- `start_day` is in the format YYYY/MM/DD;
- `start_time` is in the format HH:mm.

With an initial date of 2016/07/20 10:00, x=2 and y=5 I get the following on the console:

```
2016/07/20 10:00
2016/07/20 12:00
2016/07/20 14:00
2016/07/20 16:00
2016/07/20 18:00
```

So it's working correctly. I get a repeating event every 2 hours, starting at 10:00 hours that repeats 5 times.

However, if I change the x to 8, I get this:

```
2016/07/20 16:00
2016/07/21 00:00
2016/07/21 08:00
2016/07/21 16:00
2016/07/22 00:00
```

Why does it start at 16:00 now? Shouldn't it start at 10:00 like before and go to 18:00 next?

Comment: 1. Check your assumptions. Is it possible your input is getting changed? Log every variable to make sure.  2. Once you are sure it's a bug look for it here, and post it if someone hasn't already. https://github.com/bunkat/later/issues

Comment: I logged my variables and they were not changing, so I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Anyway, I posted it on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's outdated, but still, for future generations.
The trick is, as I get it, that it occurs every **8th** hour, in your example, every hour which number can be divided into 8. If you'll try with your `x=2` again, but starting with 11:00, you'll find out that it's still `12:00 14:00 16:00` and so on, and not `11:00 13:00` and `15:00`.
Really weird behaviour.